# Convert FedEx beta webservice to live

Tags: asp.net, fedex

I'm trying to convert beta web-service to live. after removing **beta** word from the web-service [i.e. in web.config: endpoint address="https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate"], this web service is not fetching the value. Any suggestions, why this is happening or I'm missing any procedure. Any guidance/suggestions on this.

Comment: What do you mean by _removing beta word from the web-service_? If you edit your question to include detail about exactly what you are doing, then we might be able to help.

Comment: in web.config: endpoint address="https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate", i removed beta and samething i did in WSDL file.

Comment: OK, so what do you mean by _is not fetching the value_? Is an exception getting thrown? Could you show us the (minimal) code that would allow us to replicate the issue you're facing?

Answer (score 4):

To move a system from testing to production is not only needed to remove the word beta from the testing URL address:

From:

```
"https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate";
```

To:

```
"https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate";
```

(when doing this change make sure you are replacing ALL occurrences of  wsbeta. to ws. in your solution.)

But also you need to change the MeterNumber, include the Password and Key. When you sign up for the Production Key you will get all this information on the email and also you'll get the Key as soon as you sign up (you won't get that key on the email so be careful and write down that information).

With those pieces of information you should be good to go. If you are getting an exception that's a different story, let us know what exception you are getting.